# tabu.sty not found

Tags: latex, markdown

I am getting the following error while producing pdf beamer file. I am trying to solve this but I could not be successful yet. I will really be grateful if you can help.

> ```
> ! LaTeX Error: File `tabu.sty' not found.
>
> Type X to quit or <RETURN> to proceed,
> or enter new name. (Default extension: sty)
>
> Enter file name: 
> ! Emergency stop.
> <read *> 
>
> l.77 ^^M
>
> pandoc: Error producing PDF
> Error: pandoc document conversion failed with error 43
> In addition: Warning message:
> In format.POSIXlt(as.POSIXlt(x, tz = tz), format = format, usetz = usetz,  :
>   unknown timezone 'zone/tz/2017c.1.0/zoneinfo/Europe/Istanbul'
> Execution halted
> ```

Comment: try installing a full LaTeX distribution

Comment: On my host, `apt-file search tabu.sty` give: "`texlive-latex-extra`". If on Debian based (Ubuntu and others), try this: `apt install texlive-latex-extra`!

Comment: @F.Hauri Submit your comment as a solution so it can be accepted.

Comment: @Luk164 IOk, done!

Comment: It is a really good thing you get this error message. The tabu package is more or less broken and you spare yourself a lot of unnecessary pain if you don't use it. (also read the notes in https://github.com/tabu-issues-for-future-maintainer/tabu )

Answer (score 23):

If on Windows using Miktex Console:

- Under Packages, find `tabu`
- Click it, and press the "plus" to install it.

Answer (score 3):

You have to install package who contain `tabu.sty`.

### Debian based

On my debian installation, I could run:

```
apt-file search tabu.sty
texlive-latex-extra: /usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/tabu/tabu.sty
```

If `apt-file` is not installed, you could go to

https://packages.debian.org/search?searchon=contents&keywords=tabu.sty

or, if on ubuntu:

https://packages.ubuntu.com/search?searchon=contents&keywords=tabu.sty&suite=eoan

Both search engines will print:

> ```
> /usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/tabu/tabu.sty   texlive-latex-extra
> ```

So you have to install `texlive-latex-extra`:

```
apt install texlive-latex-extra
```

### RPM based

On my fedora, I could run:

```
dnf whatprovides */tabu.sty
Last metadata expiration check: 0:22:14 ago on sam 09 mai 2020 13:24:58.
texlive-tabu-9:svn49707-19.fc32.noarch : Flexible LaTeX tabulars
Repo        : fedora
Matched from:
Filename    : /usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/tabu/tabu.sty
```

So you have to install `texlive-tabu`

```
dnf install texlive-tabu
```

### Not from distribution

You even could download `tabu` directly from [CTAN: Comprehensive TeX Archive Network](https://www.ctan.org/) at:

[`https://www.ctan.org/pkg/tabu`](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/tabu)