# save_kable() in R does not compile LaTeX table

Tags: r, pdf, latex, knitr

I'm working on a convenience function in R that prints a publication quality LaTeX table from some common model objects. It all works just great for me on my Mac, but I've built it largely for a colleague who's on a PC, for whom the file writing fails when calling `save_kable()` from the `kableExtra` package.

We get no output whatsoever from this. No pdf and no error messages.

A simple reproducible example, which fails in the same way, is as follows:

```
library(knitr)
library(here)
library(kableExtra)

outfile = here("test_table.png")
table = head(iris)
latex =  kable(x = table, format = "html")
save_kable(x = latex, file = outfile)
```

When using `as_image()`, we get the following "cannot find file" error:

Error in include_graphics(temp_png, dpi = img_dpi) :
Cannot find the file(s): "C:/R Projects/export-anova/test.pdf"

which has been [talked about before](https://community.rstudio.com/t/knittr-include-graphics-image-png-cannot-find-files/82959) in the context of `blogdown`. But that's not our context.

Other potentially relevant tidbits:

1. We can save table images with `format = 'html'`, but they are not formatted properly. We want `booktabs`.
2. If we use the above to output LaTeX code, rather than a file, then Knit with RMarkdown, we do get the correct output, but it's a full page document that needs to be cropped.
3. Same results with extensions .pdf, .png, and .jpeg

Running Windows 10, R version 4.1.2, and kableExtra version 1.3.4. The LaTeX settings in RStudio are below.

Any ideas? Seems like we're so close!

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem turned out to be missing LaTeX dependencies. The `kableExtra` package creates a `.tex` file with a long list of required packages (see below), but MikTex, the Tex distribution we were using, was unable to automatically install them, and the errors didn't propagate through to R. [Here is a post](https://github.com/haozhu233/kableExtra/issues/118) with some useful details.

There are a number of solutions, each for a different distribution.

1. Use TexLive, rather than MikTex. I use TexLive on my Mac, and it appears to have no trouble locating and installing the dependencies. The downside is that it's gigantic (>7GB to MikTex's <1GB).
2. For MikTex, you can get the packages downloaded with a combination of two approaches. First, set `keep_tex = TRUE` in `kableExtra::save_kable()`, which should produce the .tex file for compilation. Next, compile it at the command line with `xelatex yourtable.tex`. You can't use `latex yourtable.tex`, since [this compiler can't work with the required `fontspec` package](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/75267/the-fontspec-package-requires-either-xetex-or-luatex-to-function). This may download all that you need. If it doesn't, check the log file for a missing `.sty` file: we needed to manually download the `tabu` package. You can [manually install the missing files](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47613096/tabu-sty-not-found) from MikTex Console: Packages > Search for "tabu" > "+" to install. Rinse, repeat until you have all the packages you need. You could do this for all the dependencies, but there are a lot, so might as well let the compiler do as much work as possible first, then backfill as needed.
3. Compile with [TinyTex in R](https://yihui.org/tinytex/). Create the `.tex` file as above (`keep_tex = TRUE'). Then:

```
install.packages("tinytex")
tinytex::install_tinytex()
tinytex::xelatex("mytable.tex")
```

TinyTex will automatically download the required packages and should compile a pdf. The benefit is that you don't need a beefy Tex distro, but you need the added step of creating the tex file, then manually compiling.

Here's the `.tex` file generated for the example above:

```
\documentclass[border=1mm, preview]{standalone}
\usepackage[active,tightpage]{preview}
\usepackage{varwidth}
\usepackage{amssymb, amsmath}
\usepackage{ifxetex,ifluatex}
\usepackage{fixltx2e}
\usepackage{polyglossia}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{longtable}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{wrapfig}
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage{colortbl}
\usepackage{pdflscape}
\usepackage{tabu}
\usepackage{threeparttable}
\usepackage{threeparttablex}
\usepackage[normalem]{ulem}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{makecell}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{xltxtra,xunicode}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\begin{document}

\begin{tabular}{rrrrl}
\toprule
Sepal.Length & Sepal.Width & Petal.Length & Petal.Width & Species\\
\midrule
5.1 & 3.5 & 1.4 & 0.2 & setosa\\
4.9 & 3.0 & 1.4 & 0.2 & setosa\\
4.7 & 3.2 & 1.3 & 0.2 & setosa\\
4.6 & 3.1 & 1.5 & 0.2 & setosa\\
5.0 & 3.6 & 1.4 & 0.2 & setosa\\
5.4 & 3.9 & 1.7 & 0.4 & setosa\\
\bottomrule
\end{tabular}
\end{document}
```